# Using flask_restful's reqparse, are you able to ignore values not included in params or json?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Let's say you have a request coming for your API and you're using `flask_restful.reqparse` to handle the parameters and body of request.

```
POST {{url}}/users
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "firstName": "First",
    "lastName": "Last",
    "age": 25
}
```

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("firstName", type=str)
parser.add_argument("lastName", type=str)
parser.add_argument("age", type=int)
parser.add_argument("valueInQuestion", type=str)
```

Is it possible for you to not include values not found in the request when calling `.parse_args()`? For example, in the parser above we have `valueInQuestion` but the request body doesn't contain this field.

What I'm getting back from the parser is: `{'firstName': 'First', 'lastName': 'Last', 'age': 25, 'valueInQuestion': None}`.

What I WANT to get back from the parser is: `{'firstName': 'First', 'lastName': 'Last', 'age': 25}` because `valueInQuestion` not included.

EDIT: I know I can filter `None` values from a dict. I'm not looking to do this because if the user hits a POST request with `{...valueInQuestion: null}` I want to retain that value, not filter it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is parameter `store_missing` for `Argument` constructor - it is set to `True` by default. By setting this argument to `False` we get only values passed in request and other parser parameters are just skipped, so we get dictionary without `None` values. In case anyone is looking for solution, this parameter may help.

Source:
[flask-restful/reqparse.py](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/4f27b96815ad33ba8f4fab94459b1f7f62b9aa5b/flask_restful/reqparse.py#L68)

Edit:

[reqparse docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html) say "*The whole request parser part of Flask-RESTful is slated for removal and will be replaced by documentation on how to integrate with other packages that do the input/output stuff better (such as [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)). This means that it will be maintained until 2.0 but consider it deprecated. Don’t worry, if you have code using that now and wish to continue doing so, it’s not going to go away any time too soon.*"

Comment: Thanks for the late answer! I've moved on from this project and rolled out my own solution but this would've helped so I'm marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just filter out items from a dict that has a value with None, just in case If this a option for you

res = {k:v for k,v in your_dict.items() if v is not None}

Comment: Yes, I could do that. However, there's a huge difference between a request with `{...'valueInQuestion': null}` and that field not included at all. I would prefer it if there were a way to not include it in the dict in the first place. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In Python, the 'null' object is the singleton None, {...'valueInQuestion': null} is invalid code then null is not defined. So when valueInQuestion value is set the above code doesnt filter them out. I Hope i get you right.

Comment: While it's true that Python uses `None` to represent `null` - that isn't the case with JSON sent from a POST request. So I want `POST {...'valueInQuestion': null}` to translate to `{...'valueInQuestion': None}` in Python. I want `POST {}` to translate to `{}` in python NOT `{...'valueInQuestion': None}`.

Comment: Then use request.get_json() that does what u want, you can also look into Marshmallow If you want todo validitation. Br

Answer (score 0):

In my case i filtered out the None values before returning the args dictionary

```
@organization_routes.route('', methods=['PATCH'])
def update():
    data = validate_update_request()
    return controller.update(data)

def validate_update_request():
    parser=reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('name', type=str, help="organization name", required=False, location="json")
    parser.add_argument('country', type=str, help="organization country", required=False, location="json")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args_dict = {key: value for key, value in args.items() if value is not None}
    return args_dict
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).